# Can we clean up the [macbook] and [macbookpro] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

Today we deleted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673587/macbook-pro-15-retina-mid-2015-trackpad-not-clicking) that was tagged [macbookpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbookpro). The tag didn't have an excerpt at that time, so I added one to redirect general computing questions to either Super User or Apple.SE.

Given the special nature of the hardware, programming questions about that hardware are on-topic, so the tag is okay, as long as the questions address a programming issue.

There are a number of questions in [macbookpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbookpro) and [macbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbook) that are off-topic, like the example I showed earlier, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39548959/578411).

If you have some time left and flags or votes to spend, can you go over those 164 questions in [macbookpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbookpro) and 129 questions in [macbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbook) and moderate them accordingly? Some users have suggested to burninate the tag, but I'm not enough of an subject matter expert to make that call.

Comment: They said it can be cleaned using water http://i.stack.imgur.com/KiKdV.png

Comment: Do you have any examples where those tags are relevant? I see questions about the operating system or Apple SDKs, but the device doesn't seem relevant to any of the questions I see so far. Wouldn't deleting the tags be better?

Comment: @Jacob I'm not into that stack at all but [maybe this, although broad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521656/mute-macbook-pro-when-computer-is-shutting-down) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821293/opencl-command-queue-cl-queue-out-of-order-exec-mode-enable-not-working-macos) seems in scope. Feel free to write an answer that advocates burnination. I'm happy to put it on the socvr backlog in that case.

Comment: @rene Neither of those questions is actually specific to the MacBook Pro. In both cases, the OP was using a MacBook Pro, but the question would apply, respectively, to 1) any Mac and 2) any Mac with an nVidia graphics chip. (Which isn't even all MacBook Pros!)

Comment: Seems more tied to the operating system than the hardware. For example the opencl question would probably have worked if a Linux distribution had been bootcamped onto the macbook. IMO, light a fire.

Comment: Also there is [tag:bootcamp] tag that should also be burninated IMO

Answer (score 14):

I would suspect that any programming issues would be related to the OS rather than the hardware, and even if it was the hardware it would be a specific chipset etc.

The "Macbook" or "Macbook Pro" merely represent a form-factor and have nothing to do with the components, depending on which variation someone purchases the components within each form-factor differ anyway (nVidia, AMD for retina/non-retina displays; SSD,HDD or Hybrid depending on which size etc.), and differ again dependant on which year the model was produced.

On this basis, I would suggest that there are no examples where [macbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbook) or [macbookpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbookpro) would be related to the programming element and should be burninated.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a snapshot of questions with either tag from SEDE that may still need to be deleted (or even potentially salvaged, but I'm not holding my breath).

**Closed already** (please delete them if needed):
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27196016 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27949315 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29551570 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/34431719 primarily opinion-based</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/32565228 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37151231 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/26339773 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/32291115 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/10795663 primarily opinion-based</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/3887581 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40925421 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/38659183 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40458351 primarily opinion-based</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45895149 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/31218148 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/31901470 duplicate</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/32630079 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/20162784 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/34691389 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40458351 primarily opinion-based</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40352316 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/18069471 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/32036953 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/34533821 off-topic</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/4457500 too broad</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/22221799 duplicate</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37831841 duplicate</s>
<s>https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/22975104 off-topic</s>
https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7700155 too broad

**Still open** (need to be reviewed):
[How to test pinch events on a web page on a Macbook](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/11459629)
[WPF - Two Finger Horizontal scrolling on Macbook pro trackpad](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/21146183)
[Flash webcam settings on macbook (and potentially other cameras)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/2178353)
[OpenCV + Ubuntu 11.04 + Macbook Pro: Can't initialize webcam?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/8160229)
[OpenCV- Webcam frame not working on macbook in Java](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/17776399)
[Macbook camera won't turn off and a minor C# aforge issue](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/31979171)
[Is there any API MacBook to get clamshell mode?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/2235232)
[Bespin and Macbook scroll gestures](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/3554516)
<s>[Capturing gestures from MacBook Pro touchpad with Flex (Flash)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/4170697)</s>
[VMware Fusion virtualization - Do dedicated graphics and disk RPM make much difference?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7827991)
[MacBook multi-touch pad, MouseEvent and JavaNativeExceptions](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/21487418)
[How do you control the Apple MacBook "Sleep" light?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/2010713)
[Controlling Mac's front led](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27550396)
[HTML5/Javascript - Is it possible to get the absolute coordinates of a touch event on a Macbook Trackpad in the browser?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29384582)
<s>[Is there a way to access haptic trackpad feedback on the new MacBooks?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/33249331)</s>
[GLSL version on my macbook is not the same as one would expect](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/14552752)
[How to generate MD5 fingerprint using macbook 10.5.8 for Android?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/10580974)
[body: overflow-x - still able to scroll over with trackpad](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/10148879)
[How to close NSWindow and remove the application Icon from dock menu, yet](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/10843392)
[Visual Studio source window and Bootcamp keyboard mapping](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/12106981)
[How to install weinre on mac?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/12153283)
[Execute command just before Mac going to sleep](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/13534167)
[How can I change one single colour on Mac OS X screen (similar to invert colours)?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/13614891)
[PHP Create outlook/thunderbird/macbook scripts to manage email accounts](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/14857398)
<s>[dyld_shared_cache extract_dylibs failed with iPad4, Xcode4.2, MacBook](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/14979275)</s>
<s>[RoR - Discourse uninitialized constant JsLocaleHelper error](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/16501317)</s>
[Turn on background color when highlighting with C-SPC on a mac?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/18090378)
[html audio not working on macbook and ios, but works on imac -- weird](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/25440657)
[How do I set the UEFI memory map for a MacBook with Bad RAM?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/28033994)
<s>[TextField Keyboard bring me back to my first View](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29425778)</s>
<s>[Second click not registering unless mouse moved - Chrome app on Macbook](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29525787)</s>
[git line-ending issues in macos](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29893367)
[How to use shell_exec xampp php in a Mac](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/30549181)
[Android Studio in Mac, Cannot Paste Images to Res/Drawable](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/33977900)
<s>[VIM exit's INSERT Mode when using Arrow Keys on Macbook AIr](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/33980996)</s>
[JavaScript/HTML in browser on Mac](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/34559957)
[No such file or directory in MAC Terminal](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/36176289)
[Java Html Renderer on Macbook Bootcamp Windows](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/36858393)
[Xcode quits unexpectedly every time I open Xcode](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37207052)
[Dead tab button in Visual Studio 2015](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/33502055)
[Macbook late 2011 Heating After installing SSD and RAM](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37435809)
<s>[How to get real element size on "retina" displays?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37723620)</s>
[Testing a web app for macs - is IPad ok?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/3703381)
[Uninstalling older java version from mac os x el capitan](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37990591)
[Eclipse Palette unavailable](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/22362749)
[Android app running on device access localhost server (on MacBook) in my case](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/22372599)
[How to run Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 on MacBook Pro using VirtualBox?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/22479082)
[Problems with downloading Composer (PHP) on Macbook?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/24137543)
[Problems with installing Symfony 2?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/24147208)
<s>[Can't access "Applications" in Directory?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/24172246)</s>
[Get Macbook screen size from terminal/bash](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/24972338)
[Can't install Quartus II 13.0 SP1 on RedHat 6](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/25390234)
[How to determine which hardware I'm running on in MacOSX](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/25652727)
[Ghostscript not writable](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/25695934)
[Google Canary - on Macbook Air OSX 10.9.4 is giving error](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/25763088)
[Error (internetKeychainItemForServer:withUsername:path:port:protocol:) - The specified item could not be found in the keychain](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/26003538)
[How can I stop the IntelliJ icon in the dock from bouncing, without turning off bouncing for all applications](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/26642107)
[Connecting to sql server from mac](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/26643093)
[MacBook MediaQueries](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/26848497)
[Sublime Text autocomplete suggestions looks corrupt, how to fix?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27096511)
<s>[Android developing from pc to Mac](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/30648940)</s>
<s>[Firebase - Developing locally with User Authentication on the iOS (MacBook)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/31307882)</s>
[Can't search app store while using Charles Proxy as proxy server](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/31815442)
[Use theano in a macbook pro without NVIDIA card](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/32101249)
[Is it normal that my 2015 macbook air having trouble at running a simple while loop?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/32212910)
[ctrl + insert on a mac while connected using vim on a virtual machine running windows](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/32279538)
[How to know if the Mac has retina?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/11294221)
[Mapping Super Keys to Control in xorg.conf?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/14094456)
[Xcode won't compile or index project](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/15015605)
[cannot connect to host 127.0.0.1 Virtualbox](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/18364964)
<s>[How to dump and auto connect the wifi setting from MACBOOK?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/23190051)</s>
[How to take screen shot by command in Macbook via cronjob](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/24180443)
[Using Visual Studio, SQL Server, etc Windows 7 on MacBook Pro 15" (2010 model)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/3111665)
[How to develop an iphone application on Windows OS?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/4030695)
[How do I write to an NSObject from within a C function that doesn't see Obj-C variables?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/5798856)
[Bad Results: time(NULL) and clock()](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/5909556)
[Eclipse won't recognize my android phone -> Can't debug](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7371741)
[Is there a way to query the current brightness level of a the MacBook LCD?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/547691)
[Windows Mobile Development on MacBook Pro?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/2422530)
[Silverlight development compability issues](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/4225981)
[Installing WWW-development system on Macbook](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/5260370)
[C and C++ programming on MacBook](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/6100257)
[OSX Leopard - throttle a shared internet connection](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/9259805)
[NoMachine NX 'p' key not working for Macbook Pro vs Fedora](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/9921046)
[Get the internal macbook screen with NSScreen](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/10469563)
[How to install JDK1.7 on Mac](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/33234284)
<s>[Bad font in macOS Chrome](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43116784)</s>
[CentOS VM with Bridged Network Vhosts Can't Be Accessed](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/6805057)
[Installing Metasoploit Framework on Mac OSX Sierra](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44030064)
[JetBrains products not showing FN keys on touchbar](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43199785)
[Corrupt behavior of a primitive C program on a MacBook Pro, Windows XP, VS 2008 Express Edition](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/4604676)
[How to do OpenGL 3 programming on OS X with a GeForce 9400](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/5294295)
[Turning on encryption on SandForce controllers in OCZ SSDs](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/8360118)
[Macbook Pro running VMWare Fusion 4 on Native apple partition or Bootcamp partition?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/9204350)
[CALayer rendering caused memory leak on new MacBook Pro with OSX 10.7.4](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/12947912)
[Is it possible to programmatically turn on the Macbook Pro's keyboard backlight for individual keys?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/3124181)
[Minimum Bootcamp partition size for Windows development](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/4174189)
[With terminal on Macbook pro why can't I use the "delete button" to remove text on 'nled' command](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7450204)
[Don't automatically switch to the higher-end discrete GPU](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/8870304)
[how can I change the brightness of the keyboard backlight](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/9408255)
[time(NULL) Returning Inconsistent Values on Macbook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/12648473)
[MATLAB's gpuArray; insufficient compute capability](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/13123368)
[Unable to select last option in pop up eclipse on mac book pro osx](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/16388002)
[Capture MacBook Pro iSight video with C++](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/3797955)
[How to programmatically determine native pixel resolution of Retina MacBook Pro screen on OS X?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/13859109)
[How to disable Macbook Pro from switching to a high performance graphics card in Cocoa?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/4177552)
[Building multiple ports (using macports) at the same time](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/4202949)
[Is there a way to pause execution of a running Java program in Eclipse on Macbook Pro?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/4252416)
[Android ADB fails to display devices on 2011 Macbook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/5412539)
[Can't deploy xap to windows phone 7 device using MacBook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/6976782)
[Polling the accelerometer/motion sensor in a MacBook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7032767)
[Git repository on a machine with a static IP](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7231779)
[On OSX Lion XCode shuts down the MacBook](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7356632)
[Vim in OSX: How to paste text from open window into a open file in vim?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7426175)
[Eclipse SVN plugin install fail on mac pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7443342)
[What are the requirements does it take to get a Adobe air App running On a Ipad?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/8246841)
[What's needed to support non-square matrices in GLSL shader?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7561003)
[How can I test for OpenCL compability?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7892955)
[Best solution for running visual studio on os x lion](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/8206260)
[MacBook Pro crashing - from Android Emulator?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/8920694)
[rails3 app stopped working when the first access on mac](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/8951583)
[ReBinding Right-Alt Key in XEmacs](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/9251142)
[Cocoa App Renders Differently on Macbook Pro vs Mac Mini](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/9570551)
[How to develop a website for retina display?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/12000091)
[Share Web (Mac OS X 10.7.4) isn't working](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/12332076)
[How to use Xcode "move-line-up" shortcut on German keyboard of Macbook pro?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/13326419)
[Media Queries: Target retina macbook pro only](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/13747364)
[macbook arch linux refit update partition table not working](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/13943300)
[Creating Retina-capable programs with Eclipse on MacBook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/14135400)
[QT USB hardware ID detection Mac OS 10.8.x and Mac Book (Pro)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/15017917)
[How do web browsers deal with compressed resolution?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/15237775)
[Creating mark-up for non-retina display on Mac Book Pro with Retina](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/16193010)
[Prevent OpenGL.framework from Loading in Cocoa App](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/4054788)
[Does Mac need JDK (5 or 6) or Eclipse for developing Android Apps?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/3636897)
[How to activate nVidia cards programmatically on new MacBookPros for CUDA programming?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/3033463)
[Is there a way to get the magic mouse or MacBook Pro trackpad to work with the iphone simulator?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/2958435)
[vb.net on macbook(bootcamp) text is broken](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40974527)
[Touchbar support in python](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41534458)
[How Does Xcode Use The Macbook Pro Touchbar?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41796117)
[Creating a Macbook Pro Touchbar .dylib extension](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45270429)
[Strategy for using emacs now that Apple removed the escape key?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42814936)
[Error:Could not read cache value from '/Users/gsp/.gradle/daemon/2.10/registry.bin'](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40381726)
[Android OpenCV MacOS "Error:error: cannot find -lrt"](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44477569)
[How to transfer ios app generated data to macbook?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/39384603)
[Connect to a BLE device using MAC ios](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/39389005)
[Writing to a mac csv not working using python file writter](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/39777207)
[Error DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. on windows 10 on a macbook (dualboot)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42020845)
[How to read files of the internal drive of MacBook Pro from another Mac OS booted from USB?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44542059)
[Connect to MAMP local server (MacBook) from Windows computer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/38030710)
<s>[XCode: how to compare\merge code coverage reports](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/38060362)</s>
<s>[Macbook pro mid 2010, xcode randomly reboot computer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/38174645)</s>
[GNUPlot Does not show anything In Mac Terminal](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/38366139)
[Jsoup not installed on macbook pro? Class Test has compile errors jsoup](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40968391)
[Weird colour rendering in Chrome after macos Sierra](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/39839334)
[omnett++ installation issues on mac book pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/39882478)
[Strange trouble command line mac mongoDB](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/39946299)
[Can't connect to mac in visual studio](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40064420)
<s>[Netbeans 8.1 is lagging on Macbook Pro Retina running OS X El-Capitan](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40316950)</s>
[library geoocode, reshape and dplyr not active on macbook](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40399919)
[Silently downloading a .txt file to a macbook's desktop](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40619349)
<s>["Err_Connection_Refused" http sites cannot be opened, unless they're https on chrome browser macbook](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40877361)</s>
[phpmyadmin Cannot connect: invalid settings on mac after changing permsion setting in Xammp files to read and write for admin](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40893905)
[Can't open JAR files with JRE installed?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42875881)
[Netbeans: Customize Toolbars in Mac Sierra 10.12.4 Not Working](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43475456)
[How can I initialize `libdc1394` on Docker](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43425714)
[How do I download Eclipse on my Mac?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43750435)
[Localhost taking too long to respond MAMP running IPB](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44507949)
[Downloaded Python 3.6 but terminal is still saying I'm using python 2.7.12](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44615007)
[Docker not able to use all of Macbook's CPU cores](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44641143)
[How to delete trello task using keyboard on macbook](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44990531)
[Proxy cache refresh issue on Mac Xcode's simulator (MacBook)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45398384)
<s>[Logging MacBook firewall is empty](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45568865)</s>
[What is a Minecraft server and how would one hack it?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45686385)
[Thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter not found in Swift using getifaddrs()](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40695674)
[Gdb debug "terminated exit value: 0" error eclipse on mac](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41162363)
[How to use directly function key (F1 - F9) instead of pressing fn + function key in IDE in OSX?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41231880)
[Cannot run docker in macbook white](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43374891)
[The connection to adb is down in OSX system](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43579124)
[Apache Ant Installation In Mac](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44275469)
[Changing the OpenGL Context Version for QGLWidgets in Qt 4.8.6 on OS X](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/24873533)
[Eclipse Luna on Retina MBP blurry text](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27304388)
[SecureCRT vertical scroll speed using Trackpad is too fast on MacBook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27497133)
[Cant access phpMyAdmin after changing the privileges username and password (ERROR1405)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/28779770)
[Pixelated endroid emulator on retina screen](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29020728)
[Android Emulator GenyMotion(w/ VirtualBox) causes New 13'' Macbook Pro Yosemite 10.10.2 to crash(Resolved)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29064165)
[Up and Right arrows on Mac adds an extra comma and dot](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29241908)
[High resource usage while running CodeSchool angular.js tutorial](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29445459)
[AVX _mm256_sin_ps missing on OSX i7 AVX2 Retina MacBook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/30362553)
[glDrawElementsInstanced freezes or slow down at 18680 instances](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/30623737)
[How can I download SPSS for macbook?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/30729855)
[Why isn't Xcode running on my Macbook Pro?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/30879889)
[Capturing frames from macbook isight with PIL](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/30964553)
[How to set environment variables in Yosemite OSX?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/31009946)
[How to list all modules python 2.7 and 3.4 have installed for MacOSX](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/31306894)
[Python - identify the type of device](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/31370783)
[How can I enable my MacBook Pro GPU optimization for theano?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/32045279)
[docker-machine virtualbox image locations on OSX](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/32271499)
[Visual studio Code installation failed in OSX El Capitan](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/33712397)
[Kinect 2 on Mac, The kinect is connected to Hi-Speed USB not SuperSpeed](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/33917354)
[How to find the location of modules for python3 and debug an ImportError](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/34078382)
[Setting up the Oracle database on Macbook Pro (OS X Yosemite)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/32827872)
[WinObjC in Macbook](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/32888338)
[Docker pull error: no space left on device](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/33421156)
[Any way to detect Force Click with Javascript?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/33506623)
[macbook can not access apache after edited username](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/33553749)
[On making a new script " StackTrace: wapi_shm_file_open: shared file [File_Name] open error: Permission denied" appears](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/34464477)
[OpenCL command queue (CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE) not working (MacOS)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/16821293)
[A loop unexpectedly goes running infinitely in the Bash script](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/26022332)
[Start of tomcat failed](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/23081395)
[Reading pixel color on Bootcamp Windows 8.1](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/23542167)
[Coding/Running Java in MacBook Pro with Eclipse or NetBeans](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/23839723)
[Serilized file from Java and `sizeof` operator in C language (JNI) are unequal](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/24538260)
[Running windows under virtual box for software development - performance issues?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/25413372)
[Rails Console still running after Control-Z](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/25455412)
[Unable to connect the android device to Windows 7](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/25545232)
[iOS Simulator changes MacBook tint](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/17477657)
[Best way to transfer MySQL databases to Mac?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/18265432)
[Macbook Pro 15", backspace not working with VIM?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/18419923)
[Windows Phone Emulator on MacBook Pro (2013)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/20683464)
[MBP Retina Isight and FFmpeg](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/21138460)
[MPlayer Webcam on Macbook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/21769718)
[Incorrect Results - OpenCL on Intel HD 4000](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/23140000)
[How to go to the first and last line using keyshort with IDEA on macbook pro?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/25707706)
[sudo service command not found when installing mongodb](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/25827255)
[How to use a french MacBook Pro keyboard with Ubuntu?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/26205801)
[Pararells + Mac OS + Visual Studio 2013](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/26711976)
[Use local server of Mac on iPhone](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27054012)
[Cant log in to BeagleBone Black's SSH through my Mac?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27063878)
[WebGL: performance of >65k vertex mesh](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27137605)
[PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27580987)
[Macbook Apache folders](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27674720)
[Opening a Keynote Presentation using AppleScript (Keynote 6.5.2)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/27954594)
[GetUserMedia not working on Macbook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/28206090)
[How do I ensure that Mongo binaries are in my PATH - in my shell' rc (~/.bashrc) on a Mac](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/28267773)
[Mute Macbook pro when computer is shutting down](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29521656)
[How can I push a repository to my computer and my online server?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29905817)
[MAMP on OSX Yosemite - Virtual host name gives 404 error](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/29948998)
[How to resolve the pipe character "|" not typing in in Xcode text editor?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/31937380)
[Permission denied to edit the file in sysroot which used sshfs](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/34783678)
[Custom font works on a desktop browser not a mobile device](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/35635569)
[Which video formats works on ipad and Macbook Pro?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/36975698)
[VB.NET Application re-sizing by itself?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37135036)
[When adding background image : Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37501394)
[Running GUI apps on docker container with a MacBookPro host](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37523980)
[Error:No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37565243)
[AnimationDrawable Error on button click](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37676186)
[Cannot Move Objects in Design Layout](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37810042)
[ImageView Intersect Not being detected](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37847663)
[Get Animation List current Image Index](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37904133)
<s>[MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) run new AS project,cpu 100%](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/38167936)</s>
[How do I resolve this error when installing Ruby on a Macbook Pro (Mountain Lion) with RVM?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/38285481)
[Optimal block size for unrolled linked lists](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/38380724)
[Compare GCEUs to performance of physical machine (e.g. MacBook Pro)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/38417933)
[Ngrok setup an SSL local tunnel to an existing Vhost](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/39750034)
[How can you test Touch ID for macOS?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40414077)
[Visual Studio Android Emulator internet connection](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40468580)
[Update to Sierra 10.12.1, C compilers, Xcode, and grace not working](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40499725)
[Can I run Cuda or opencl on intel iris?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40560336)
[Python 3 files are assigned to wrong filename which I specify](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40688465)
[Unable to Open my website in Safari](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/37249637)
[OS X: Launch daemon doesn't start until user logs in](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/38828858)
[Android studio can not install Support repository and SDK Tools](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40244090)
[Which global gitignore am I using?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40164234)
[Dead tab button in Visual Studio 2015](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/33502055)
[How to determine which hardware I'm running on in MacOSX](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/25652727)
[Installing Metasoploit Framework on Mac OSX Sierra](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44030064)
[Desktop spaces are moving by their own](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40747127)
[WebStorm - Turn Power Save Mode off when laptop is charging](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40779944)
["mysql: command not found" even though path is set](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40808916)
[OpenLayers 3 and the MacBook Pro high performance GPU](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40830357)
[Disable MacBook Pro high performance GPU in a QuickLook plugin](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40831734)
[Xamarin.iOS Designer - Creating Action segue not working](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40859517)
[install windows 7 on Mac OS sierra](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40922577)
[Div inside SVG foreignObject loses its position in Mac Chrome](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40926897)
[macOS Sierra Touch Bar Icons Location](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41110454)
[Is it possible to run Alea GPU on MacBook Pro in Virtual Machine](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41113473)
[Isnt' it possible to run OpenGL 3.0 on Macbok Pro 2015 mid with glfw3?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41120025)
[Is it possible to leverage OS X Touch ID or Watch 2 Factor authentication in a webpage or app?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42103857)
[How do I start mongodb in a different terminal using a script in mac?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42278539)
<s>[Strange autocompletion behavior when typing the word "date"](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42474074)</s>
[Why does my code run quicker on my phone than my laptop?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42515980)
[xcode 8 storyboard slow in macbook pro 2016](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42527182)
[Installing PHP using Homebrew on MAC](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42537955)
[How to install osx sierra on virtualbox (on my mac)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42547762)
[Xamarin Build Error on virtualized Windows Visual Studio on macbook pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42749624)
[Visual Studio 2017 Installation breaks Windows 10 (on a MacBook Pro)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42859245)
<s>[Java blocks applications on exceptions list](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42914852)</s>
[Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 "_main"](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42945348)
[Selenium Automation through Android Studio on emulators](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43032054)
[I installed reFInd on my macbook pro 2016 with --alldrivers and now it powers up with a black screen](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43165063)
[Parameters were incorrect when running Selenium?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43201708)
[unable to look up https (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known) on git pull request](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43259967)
[Scroll animation not work in mac book retina](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43534623)
[efilogin-helper running continuously at high cpu on MacBook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44958896)
[Get Android Build from MacBook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45142918)
[MacBook pro track pad events in javascript double finger double tap](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45234678)
[Watchman Installation - Setting PATH on Macbook Pro](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45267779)
[Create React Native App ScrollView Example Errors](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45295029)
[How get an item in control center of Touch Bar on the right?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/40920204)
[Create java applications with MacBook Pro touchbar support?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41209625)
[How can i disable the touch bar functionality in Mac through Objective C or Java](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42000200)
[How to identify actual touchBar hardware is available in an Mac book using obj c?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42198926)
[What is the shortcut for commenting (block or not) on PhpStorm 2017.1 on a Macbook Pro 2016 (with touchbar)?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44395536)
[How Does Xcode Use The Macbook Pro Touchbar?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41796117)
[Wow JS solution to remove bold text not working on Macbook Pro (Google Chrome)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41670339)
[mamp on mac - start/stop mamp server on schedule to download remote files](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41773374)
[Updating Git to official distribution on MacBook Pro Sierra](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41919823)
[/usr/libexec/java_home Command](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/41931493)
<s>[osx local ip redirects to localhost instead](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42818342)</s>
[Why does scenebuilder comes blurry when moving items?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42841101)
[Can not connect to J-Link via USB on macOS Sierra](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43479101)
[Android OpenCV MacOS "Error:error: cannot find -lrt"](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44477569)
[IntelliJ IDEA debugger is too slow to start on macOS](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44680463)
[MacBook Pro (13" 2017 2TDB3) won't power up](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/44916469)
<s>[What architecture of Macbook Pro Intel Core i7 with MacOS Sierra](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45248130)</s>
<s>[Zbrush and special characters](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45394242)</s>
[IntelliJIDEA high CPU Usage (over 300%)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45607552)
[Compiling c++ with VSCode on Sierra](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45778834)
[Share my local servers with my local network devices](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/45884561)
[Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/46015589)
[Can't open JAR files with JRE installed?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42875881)
[Cannot run docker in macbook white](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/43374891)
[imac and mbp display nscollectionview different way](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/42059060)

Comment: Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeek!

Comment: Okay @CodyGray.  You win.  But the scale I was looking at the other day was smaller, thankfully...

Comment: What'd I win (other than a big list of questions to look through and close/delete)?

Comment: @CodyGray:  Well, *that*, and a sense of "I told you so Makoto" from the last time we crossed paths on a burnination effort.  The last one was so much smaller scale I didn't think we'd run into issues, but this one...yeah... *this one*...  I've learned whatever lesson needs to be learned here.

Comment: @Makoto some of this questions are on-topic IMHO, but should not be tagged with [macbookpro]. Take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294221/how-to-know-if-the-mac-has-retina)

Comment: @VadimKotov:  I did say "may"...

Comment: @Makoto do you mind if I update the list to include 3 sections? They will be: To be deleted, On-topic (can be salvaged), Already deleted

Comment: @VadimKotov: I'd say stay away from "on-topic" since that implies that they have to stick around (and that's almost subjective), but I don't have a problem with this.  I made this post CW for that reason.

Comment: I've added a section with closed questions that can be deleted

Answer (score -12):

I've gone through the questions and did a clean-up, retagging (mostly with [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx)) and flagging off-topic questions.
There are no questions tagged with [macbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbook) and [macbookpro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macbookpro) now. Those tags will be gone in 24 hours.

Comment: [This question should *not* have had its tag removed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489679/macbook-pro-dual-boot-os-x-and-windows-7-for-net-development)  It should be closed and then deleted *instead*.

Comment: @Makoto It is already closed. Feel free to delete it or ask for help on deleting it

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's going to be *that much harder* to find these questions to effectively clean them up.  Fortunately...there's a breadcrumb trail that we can use to track these down, y'know, *just* in case there were some that needed to be edited or just outright downvoted and deleted.

Comment: Ugh, yeah. Please stop single-handedly retagging questions.

Comment: @Makoto I think it's better to prevent people from tagging off-topic questions with such kind of tags by deleting them instead of waiting for a day when it all will be deleted. SO got rid of [tag:homework] after all.. Those questions were there open literally for years, and nobody cared.

Comment: @CodyGray what should I do instead? Could you guide me?

Comment: ***Not that.*** Put together a list of questions that need to be worked, then keep track of it.  Just blanket-editing the tags is going to make it harder for the rest of us to clean things up properly.

Comment: That doesn't prevent people from doing anything. It just prevents us from finding bad questions and dealing with them. Yes, sometimes off-topic questions remain open for years and nobody notices them. That's because they aren't actually hurting things. If you are going to go and dig them up, then you need to deal with the problems there. Off-topic questions should not be retagged, they should be closed and deleted.

Comment: We usually have an ongoing burnination effort that you can contribute to, if you like. Currently, it's the [entry] tag. See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349778/the-entry-tag-is-in-the-process-of-being-burninated). The guidance in the accepted answer is important, and applies to all burnination/retag exercises.

Comment: @CodyGray Even if the whole tag is off-topic (and this request was upvoted)?

Comment: A tag cannot be off-topic; only *questions* can be off-topic. And off-topic questions need to be closed and deleted. Retagging them prevents us from finding them, so this is counter-productive. Makoto has already made that point. That's why we've got a process for this. People propose tags that need to be cleaned up on Meta, we wait for a consensus to be reached, and then the process is begun.