# Another [entry] on the burnination list

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

From the tag usage guidance for [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entry):

> **This is a vague tag** that may stand for a class name, something coming in, a synonym for entity or item, ... **Try to avoid this tag.**

From its tag description:

> Entry **has many different meanings**:
>
> - a class name, in which case use tags related to class
> - something coming in
> - a synonym for entity or item, use tag entity
> - a widget on a GUI
>
> **Try to avoid this tag!!!**

"Something coming in"? "A class name"? "Try to avoid this tag"? Seriously?

The four [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) for burning a tag are:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is
   applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   No, even the tag description admits that it's vague and ambiguous.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Yeah, I guess so, at least in the sense that those are all programming concepts.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   Not really—it's too vague to add anything meaningful.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No, absolutely not, the description has a list of all of the things that it *might* mean.

The fact that its own description says to "try to avoid this tag" kind of tells you that it's a bad tag. That being the case, I'd say that this tag is pretty useless. Should it be removed?

Comment: 578 questions is a tough job, but not undoable.

Comment: Question score is +60/-0 at the time of featuring.

Comment: A search for "[tkinter] entry" yields 5811 results. There are also 266 results for "[tkinter] [entry]". I've just created a [tktinter-entry] tag, and it might be helpful to spread it around. Note that `Entry` is apparently an important widget in the Python Tkinter package.

Comment: @dfeuer Hence the "widget on a UI" bit in the description. Yeah, that makes sense, then - that new tag at least unambiguously describes the content.

Comment: @dfeuer as someone who has used `tkinter` yes entry is very important and should deservedly have its own tag

Comment: Burn it with blue-hot dragon fire.

Comment: Question score is +155/-0 when burnination was initiated. CW answer had a score of +32/-0.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) This tag has been *burninated*.

[image]

---

#### Observations/Retag Guidance:

- A number of the questions that currently have the [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entry) tag are actually about the **entry point**, which is where a program begins execution. Such questions should be retagged to [entry-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entry-point). You especially see this in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) questions, but you also occasionally see it for other languages where this concept is relevant. In many cases, it's obvious what needs to be done, since separate [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entry) and [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point) tags were used, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680199/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-the-main-method-in-java-c-c-c).
- Questions about **data entry** do not need the tag at all, except in special cases, where a [user-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-input) tag might be appropriate (but consider whether the question is really *about* user input, or whether that's just part of the example).
- A number of **Python**/**Tkinter** questions seem to be tagged [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entry). The replacement tag for the [Tkinter widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) is [tkinter-entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter-entry).
- A number of **Gtk** questions seem to be tagged [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entry). The replacement tag for the [Gtk widget](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkEntry) is [gtkentry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtkentry).
- A number of **Tcl or Perl**/**Tk** questions seem to be tagged [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entry). The replacement tag for [Tk::Entry](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk/pod/Entry.pod) or [ttk:entry](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_entry.htm) is [tkentry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkentry).
- "Entry" is the name of a control class in **Xamarin Forms**: [Xamarin.Forms.Entry](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Entry/). These questions should be retagged [xamarin.forms.entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms.entry).
- Although I didn't see any, be on the lookout for questions that need to be retagged to [directoryentry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directoryentry). **DirectoryEntry** is a .NET Framework class relevant to Active Directory.

Comment: All of these are closed now - we should probably give it 24 hours or so to see if anyone objects to the closures.

Comment: Nothing to disagree with in the 6 questions that remained, so they have now evaporated, inching me [ever so closer to my goal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356160/did-we-lose-half-a-million-questions#comment511321_356165). Tag should die a fiery death soon. I'm going ahead and marking this as complete.

Comment: aaand the tag is gone.

Answer (score 80):

This seems like a useless tag for SO and worthy of the burn.

If there are any specific programming methods that are called entry - they could be retagged to say [language-entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-entry).

The only thing I'm cautious of with burninations, is closing questions unnecessarily in an attempt to get rid of the tag.

*Cautionary note:*

My vote is - if in doubt - edit the tags to remove the [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entry) and move on. We're not all experts in every programming field and need to be mindful that when reviewing outside of our expertise, what we may think is off topic to us, may make perfect sense and be perfectly answerable to someone in the field.

Comment: entry is a topic keyword (not a language keyword) for the beginning of functions in assembly language. The corresponding topic for the end of functions is epilog. Maybe make entry/epilog because they're discussed together.

Comment: @Joshua perhaps you can add this to the [community wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355967/3956566) Cody created.

Comment: @Joshua the opposite of an epilogue is a prologue (in programming as well as literature) :)

Comment: @Joshua Hmm...I'm an assembly programmer and have never heard the term "entry" used with reference to assembly language. As hobbs said, the opposite of epilogue is prologue. The only other place "entry" would be used is to refer to an *entry point*, which should be tagged [[tag:entry-point]], as mentioned in my answer below. x86 has the `ENTER` mnemonic, but that's long obsolete and I don't see any questions referring to it. I don't think it needs its own tag.

Comment: @CodyGray: My best guess is the books I learned from used obscure synonyms. I've not seen the books elsewhere so ...