# We're NOT out of [compliance]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compliance)

50 questions.

Nearly every last one is about policy compliance, which is not related to software development (falls under [support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/)). The few that aren't could be retagged since this tag does nothing for cohesion.

Comment: It looks like a lot of the questions aren't in [compliance] with site rules. Pity I'm out of close votes for the day...

Comment: Maybe a cv-pls in the Close Vote chat for the entire tag? ;) Either way, the tag should be burned.

Comment: So is this tag being eliminated?  Or does it have legitimate use (in which case the description should be filled in)?

Comment: @wallyk Burninate = remove. There's no legitimate usage of the tag that I've seen, or can think of

Comment: @Machavity A lot of the questions are about standards [tag:compliance], which is reasonably on-topic. It's not a great tag for them, but it doesn't mean the questions are bad.

Comment: @duskwuff Then shouldn't they be tagged [standards] instead?

Comment: We found a bad tag; may we burn it?

Comment: I'm not necessarily defending the tag, but "compliance" with a policy often means compliance with governmental standards (e.g. FDA regulations for medical devices) and/or international standards. So I'm not sure that this sort of thing is related to "support for your favorite company", or that such issues are "not related to software development."

Comment: @KyleStrand Still, the vast majority of the questions with that tag are off-topic for one reason or another.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Right, which is why I said I'm not defending the tag. I'm just saying that the *stated reasoning* for considering the tag off-topic seems completely incorrect to me.

Comment: @Machavity Probably not. [tag:standards] is an equally bad tag. Ideally they'd have a tag specific to the standard, e.g. [tag:html] for HTML standards compliance.

Comment: @duskwuff So [standards] is not really in [compliance] either?

Comment: Burn them both!!!

Comment: So, everything is on hold or closed in the tag... now what?

Comment: @EJoshuaS A lot of the questions will Roomba now, and we can delete vote the rest once the 2 day requirement is up (please don't downvote so they Roomba)

Comment: In the meantime, maybe the [tag:standards] or [the "entry" tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349778/burn-the-entry-tag)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, once the questions Roomba (or are otherwise deleted), what do we do? (This is my first time participating in burniating a tag).

Comment: Once all the questions are gone the tag is deleted out of the system

Comment: They're all gone now? So should this post be flagged for moderator attention to tag it as complete?

Comment: Looks like SOCVR chipped in a ton of votes. Maybe a mod or two as well. Cool

Comment: @EJoshuaS Take a look at the tag info for [meta-tag:burninate-request]. There's a link to the burnination process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And since all the questions are now deleted...

Tag burninated!