# Stack Overflow doesn't have a [mode] where we need this tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The description of the [mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mode) tag is as follows:

> Mode is a state in which a program exposes a particular subset of its functionality.

Many of the questions tagged have nothing to do with that, they're about mode in the statistics sense.

As described, that's too vague to add anything meaningful. Even if it *were* changed to be about statistics, I doubt the need to have a separate tag for that.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?** No, not really.

**Does it add anything meaningful?** No.

**Is it on topic?** Yes, in the sense that that's actually a programming concept.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** I don't think so.

Can we burn this?

Comment: @Adriaan Done, will try to write a bit more when I get back, too.

Comment: Merge with [tag:average]?

Comment: @Shog9 Maybe... statistics is arguably less ambiguous than the current tag description. At a minimum it actually says something meaningful about the content of the question. It's a useless tag as currently described.

Comment: @Shog Can we [reduce the number of close votes required](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4) to speed up the burniation process, too? ;) (Never hurts to try to push for my pet feature request, right?)

Comment: Man... Wouldn't it be nice if it was possible to do that on a per-tag basis?

Comment: @Shog9 in descriptive statistics, mode is the value that has the higher frequency. It's only "the same" as the (arithmetic) mean/average and median on normal distributions, which are themselves very rare in the real world.

Comment: Burnination à la [mode]

Comment: Set Meta to Burnination [mode]

Comment: This is not "à la [mode]" anymore.

Comment: @matsjoyce ooh good one! I was thinking about: "Burniation [mode] engaged"

Comment: @matsjoyce do you mean "Set meta to pun"?

Comment: Should we remove this tag from all tagged questions?

Comment: @programmer5000 no, close those that should first, then we figure out what to do with the rest.

Comment: @Shog9 Can you do the "magic button thing" your burninate request post talks about to disappear this tag? [The "entry" tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349778/burn-the-entry-tag) could probably use it at this point, too (although admittedly that one probably could stand to be a little cleaner).