# Can we burninate [mode]?

Tags: support, burninate-request

[mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mode) is one of those useless meta-tags that have no inherent meaning, but simply clutter up the tag space.

Even worse, because mode as a concept has so many overloaded meanings that is largely meaningless.

Can we burninate it please?

Comment: Suggested title: Change the [mode] to burninate

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351760/so-doesnt-have-a-mode-where-we-need-this-tag - we should do this