# Did we lose half a million questions?

Tags: support, questions

I remember logging into Stack Overflow the other day and seeing the question counter being at 14.99 million. I counted back a few pages and realized "Hey, if we carry through at the same pace for the next 24 hours, we'll break 15 million questions! Hurray!"

Then I went about my day and forgot about it. Today I saw we only have 14.5 million. Now I know how that counter gets incremented is tricky, but... is there half a million questions sitting somewhere not being counted? Are there hanging chads or something? Did I possibly misremember the number?

Were we almost at 15 million questions and then lose it?

Comment: We regularly lose a lot of posts as the roomba cleans up cruft.

Comment: You can use the snapshots for data.stackexchange.com available at archive.org to verify this.  Hover over "14m" to see the exact count in the tooltip.  Nope, "a while ago" was probably 13.99 million in early June, displayed as "14m".

Comment: @MartijnPieters That’s a _lot_ of cruft… 

Answer (score 19):

So the answer is, yes I'm losing my mind and cannot count. However, we did lose a lot of posts. Hans Passant mentioned using http://archive.org so I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions caches to look at the numbers

```
Date        Count        Diff
30-Aug-17   14487029    
31-Aug-17   14494722     7693
1-Sep-17    14491247    -3475
2-Sep-17    14497049     5802
3-Sep-17    14498900     1851
4-Sep-17    14505977     7077
5-Sep-17    14511538     5561
```

So Martijn is correct, we lose a LOT of posts with the roomba, but not half a million. Clearly, I had too much to drink at beer-o-clock and misread the number.

Comment: Ah, that's disappointing. I was hoping I'd somehow managed to delete half a million posts. More work to do yet, I see.

Comment: "Who checked in all these changes to the roomba?" - a mysterious voice in New York tomorrow morning...

Comment: @CodyGray Well, [here is ~1M for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)

Comment: Yes, lets burninate [tag:php]!

Comment: I'd probably start with [tag:android], @Nathan...

Comment: you probably read 14.49 Mio.

Comment: there is only one valid php question - "why?"

Comment: @Orangesandlemons: but that question is off-topic.